Hiding Endpoints in android sources
I am currently working on a mobile app which is using some URL addresses to fetch some sensitive data, both data and addresses should not be visible to the users(or anyone with decompiling APK source codes). So I was wondering if there's any way to hide this URL addresses form who's gonna read the source through APK file.
I have thought about encrypting or obfuscating the source code so even by decompiling nothing would be visible to anyone but on the other hand they might use wire shark tool and see which packet is coming from which source and to which target;
I just need to completely hide the footprint of this server Domain and IP.
